# xcode window creation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm very new to OSX programming and I've been trying out a few examples in various articles and I've been facing a problem ; at that point I decided to follow tutorials from "Cocoa Programming for MacOSX" and Im running into the same problem.

My project name is "Random" and when I click "Build and Run", it shows the status as "Random running". However I don't see the window that pops up. Why does this happen?

I had a look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872451/xcode-program-starts-but-no-window) and unfortunately it does not help.

[EDIT]

"Random" is a Cocoa application for Mac.

[EDIT2]

I tried doing the same with a new cocoa application and the problem persists. Here is what I did. Create a new cocoa project named "blah". Click "Build and Run" - from what I am reading im supposed to see an empty window - however I dont see the same.

[EDIT3]

My Xcode version details :-

- Xcode IDE: 1610.0
- Xcode Core: 1608.0
- ToolSupport: 1591.0

Comment: What type of project is Random? Is it an iOS app, a Mac app, a command line application, or a library?

Comment: Uh, what tutorial is this exactly? What does the application, code, and xib file look like? Right now all we have is the name of the project... and type of project... that doesn't really help - more information might be nice :)

Comment: @Vervious Sure,thanks, I've made Edit2 and Edit3.

Comment: Hmmmm. Your problem is strange. The application launches, right? (You can see it in the dock?)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you will have a window visible if you have it in the xib that is loaded with you main menu and it is marked to be visible at launch... This should be all set up if you chose the window based application, if you chose document based then you will get a window when you select new from the file menu